# Unable to start debugger in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to start debugger in my SSMS '12 but when I click the debug after accepting to prompt boxes regarding permissions I get this dialogue box:

[image]

I am currently connected to a local instance on my own machine.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: and are you sure that your local instance is named "(localdb)"?

Comment: yes in object explorer i am connected to (locadb)\V11.0

Comment: While you are a developer and I can see why you put this here, I would try this question here [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: isn't SuperUser to general for this question? I has second opinions with `dba.stackexchange.com` but as it was a local dev. issue hence posted here